# Does bash cache sourced files such that it doesn't need to reparse them from disk?

Tags: bash, shell

Say I source a bash script from within `$PROMPT_COMMAND`, which is to say at every time <kbd>enter</kbd> is pressed, which makes it quite often, does bash optimize this somehow when the file wasn't changed?

EDIT:

Just to clarify, I only ask about loading the script's content from disk, not optimizing the code itself.

An example an optimization one could manually do is check if the sourced file has the same modified date and size[1], if so, then *not* read the file from disk again and use an already parsed script from memory and execute that instead. If that file contains only bash function definitions then one could also imagine an optimization where these definitions need not be changed (reevaluated) at all - given that the contents are the same.

Is checking file size and modified date sufficient to determine if a file has changed? It can certainly be subverted but given that this is what `rsync` does by default then it surely is a method to consider.

[1] If a filesystem also stores checksums for files then this would be an even better way to determine if a file on disk has or hasn't changed.

Comment: How would `bash` know what to do? The script is a black-box: you source it, and it does something. If it does something that doesn't need to be repeated every time, move that out of the script.

Comment: If the date of modification and size are the same then the contents would also be the same. I get it that one could meddle with those if one wanted to, it's a trade-off.

Comment: Another thought: I guess another factor of making sourcing of the script fast is that given how often it is sourced then it pretty much permanently sits in page cache.

Comment: *You* know that's true. How would `bash`? Scripts aren't mathematical functions. Suppose your script consisted of the single command `date`: that's going to produce different output every time it runs, even if the script itself never changes.

Comment: The time it takes to read the script is likely less than the time it takes to actually execute the commands in the script.

Comment: In general, if you want to do something during prompt setup and want that thing to perform well, that thing should be a shell function, and it should be cautiously written to do no `fork()` operations, no `exec`s of external commands, etc. (A lot of prompt commands are poorly written, meaning slow; they do things like running `git` instead of inspecting the filesystem directly, etc)

Comment: Anyhow -- forking off a subprocess to run `git` or another external command called from the file is _much_ slower than reading the file's content, so focusing on whether the text of the file is cached is putting attention in the wrong place.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments, I've tried to clarified what I meant.

Answer (score 4):

Just to avoid misunderstandings regarding the term *optimization*:

- It seems you are concerned with the time it takes to load the sourced file from the disk (this special form of optimization is usually called *caching*)
- ... not about the time it takes to executed an already loaded file (*optimization* as done by compilers, e.g. `gcc -O2`)

As far as I know, bash **neither** caches file contents **nor** does it optimize scripts. Although the underlying file system or operating system may cache files, bash would have to parse the cached file again; which probably takes longer than loading it from a modern disk (e.g. an SSD).

I wouldn't worry too much about such things unless they actually become a problem for you. If they do, you can easily ...

#### Cache the script yourself

Wrap the entire content of the sourced file in a function definition. Then source the file once on shell startup. After that, you can run the function from memory.

**define-my-prompt-command.sh**

```
my_prompt_command() {
  # a big script
}
```

**.bashrc**

```
source define-my-prompt-command.sh
PROMPT_COMMAND=my_prompt_command
```

Comment: In the light of this answer, I've now clarified what I meant by optimization, thanks!

Comment: I don't see what more you need. Why is this not an acceptable answer?

Comment: The difference is that I *would* like the file to get reloaded whenever definitions in it change. If I just load it once at bash startup then at further changes I would need to load the file manually again.

Comment: @CigaretteSmokingMan Thanks for clarifying this here. You should edit your question too (including its title). Currently, you only (explicitly) asked *"is bash caching sourced files?"* and the answer to that question is *"no"*. The caching shown at the end of my answer is only a bonus on top of that *"no"*.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add following snippet to your script :

```
if ! type reload-sourced-file > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then
    echo "This is run when you first source the file..."
    PROMPT_COMMAND=$'reload-sourced-file\n'"$PROMPT_COMMAND"
    absolute_script_path=$(realpath -e $BASH_SOURCE)
    script_previous_stat=$(stat -c "%B%y%z" $absolute_script_path)
fi

reload-sourced-file(){
    local stat=$(stat -c "%B%y%z" "$absolute_script_path")
    if ! test "$stat" = "$script_previous_stat"; then # Re-source when stat changes.
        script_previous_stat="$stat"
        echo "You'll see this message for the following Re-sourcings."
        source "$absolute_script_path"
    fi
}
```

the script will be re-sourced when stat changes. Hopefully the stat is cached by the file system.